# Visual Studio Release Build results in an executable that needs a Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT

Tags: c++, opencv

I compiled a complete C++ project as release, and as result, it requires Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT to run?

How can it be, that I compiled as a release, and it needs a debug DLL?
How can I tell, which external DLL needs it? Does OpenCV 1.0 needs
Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT?

Tamas

Comment: Wow, talk about some serious archeology (VS2005 and a 12+ year old OpenCV) :D | Hard to say what's going on without seeing some context (how the project is configured, etc) You might wanna try Dependency Walker to find out what needs the debug CRT. Maybe the project is misconfigured and links with debug build of OpenCV (in more recent builds those have suffix `d` so they're easy to tell apart, but who knows how it was in 1.0)

Comment: These libs are used:
cv.lib
cxcore.lib
highgui.lib
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib

Answer (score 0):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) might help.

Maybe you have linked against wrong open CV .lib file, so it loaded wrong DLL. Or if debug and release open CV dll are named the same, you just need to make sure release DLL is available to application in DLL search paths.